# apache2 restart error of "bad user name"

Tags: apache-2.2

Basically, I cannot restart/stop my Apache server. I receive the following error:

```
aditya@aditya-desktop:/usr/sbin$ sudo ./apache2 -k restart
apache2: bad user name ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
```

Any idea as to what is causing this error and how to resolve it?

Comment: Belongs to Server Fault.

Comment: what operating system?

Answer (score 5):

First of all I'd try to use the **apache2ctl** command for the job.

> sudo apache2ctl restart

*EDIT after petre comment:*

I think you are not using any wrapper, but trying to start the daemon running the apache2 bin directly, thus obviously not having any ENV variable being set

Comment: Good tip. All the arguments of apache2 are also available via apache2ctl, but the latter has the correct environment set. I use this wrapper script for the useful commands: apache2ctl -S or apache2ctl -M

Comment: Actually this applies to almost any ``apache2`` invocation e.g. using ``sudo apache2 -M`` to list loaded modules can be replaced by ``sudo apache2ctl -M`` - this avoids the need to have ``/etc/apache2/envvars``, which doesn't exist on my Debian Wheezy setup using default apache2 from repo.

Answer (score 3):

You don't say what system you're running, but,

```
% egrep '(User|Group)' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf 
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
```

This is the standard ubuntu setup. The user/group that apache runs at aren't set in the config file, but in `/etc/apache2/envvars`, which is sourced by the init script.

You should use the init script to restart apache, `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart` or if for some reason you can't, set your own envrionment variables and use `apachectl`.

Comment: +1 would also be my answer..

Comment: when APACHE_RUN_USER and APACHE_RUN_GROUP is not set it defaults to root.

Answer (score 1):

an error in the wrapper script - either user apache2ctl as instructed below, or search the script for the APACHE_RUN_USER variable and see what's wrong

Comment: I think he is nothing using any wrapper, but tries to start the daemon directly running the apache2 bin directly, thus obviously not having any env been set